# Use example of Intel University program in Intel Quartus - problem with Board support package?

Tags: intel, fpga, quartus, nios, bsp

I want to use a example from the Intel FPGA Monitor Program 18.1 and use it in Quartus 18.1.
It is the video example, which creates a blue box on the HDMI output and writes a littel String with white letters on top of it.

I want to use it in Intel Quartus environment , do some test-outputs on my screen and finally add some more Hardware to the Avalon system. Unfortunately it doesnt work for me as i thought xD:

**short file overview:**

Project File: DE10_Nano_Computer.qpf

QSYS Konfiguration File: Computer_System.sopcinfo

SRAM File : DE10_Nano_Computer.sof

NIOSII Main: video.c

NIOSII library: address_map_nios2.h

---

**Project includes:**

[DE10-Nano_Computer_NiosII.pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwiHq8Ha0bHoAhXOsKQKHUu6DdIQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fftp.intel.com%2FPub%2Ffpgaup%2Fpub%2FIntel_Material%2F18.1%2FComputer_Systems%2FDE10-Nano%2FDE10-Nano_Computer_NiosII.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1-HoCsnC7Vin21PNHOAsmE)

I/O Peripheral | Qsys Core

- On-chip memory
- character buffer Character Buffer for Video Display
- SD Card SD Card Interface
- Red LED parallel port Parallel Port
- Expansion parallel ports Parallel Port
- Slider switch parallel port Parallel Port
- Pushbutton parallel port Parallel
- Port JTAG port JTAG UART
- Interval timer Interval timer
- System ID System ID
- Peripheral Audio port Audio
- Video port Pixel Buffer DMA  Controller

---

**Test1:** Open FPGA Monitor Program 18.1 - create new project - select video example - sof is downloaded on FPGA - compile & load video.c **Result: works HDMI shows test-string**

**Test2:** download .sof to FPGA - Eclipse for Nios - new project simple hello world with bsp -work with .sof-put video.c and address_map_nios2.h into project- use video.c as main, **Result: works HDMI shows test-string**

**Test 3:** do the same as Test2 , **Result: random pixels in the first ~20 lines**

**Test 4:** reinstall FPGA Monitor Program 18.1 do the same as Test2 **Result: works HDMI shows test-string**

**Test 5:** do the same like Test2, doesnt work, do the same like Test4 **Result: random pixels in the first ~20 lines**

**Test 6:** copy .elf from my FPGA Monitor Program 18.1 software directory into project folder, run this this elf **Result: works HDMI shows test-string**

**Test 7:** change something of the video.c of Test 6, **Result: works HDMI shows test-string but without the blue box !**

**Test 8:** do the same like Test2 **Result: random pixels in the first ~20 lines**

**Test 9:** Check run configurations : select all combinations of processor and byte stream devices **Result: random pixels in the first ~20 lines**

**Test 10:** Switch to  FPGA Monitor Program 18.1, compile & Load video.c **Result: works HDMI shows test-string**

---

**Check:** Description in https://home.isr.uc.pt/~jfilipe/files/Final_Project_Simplified_Tutorial.pdf
( they do nearly the same...)

**Check:** Book EMBEDDED SoPC DESIGN WITH NIOS II PROCESSOR AND VERILOG EXAMPLES : They say: BSP Editor will get the sopcinfo file and support you with your access to the Hardware. Without configuring much

**Check:** Intel BSP documents : hey say: BSP Editor will get the sopcinfo file and support you with your access to the Hardware. Without configuring much

**Check:** Intel The Nios® II Processor: Hardware Abstraction Layer in youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HF7Low_sUig

---

***I suppose that something is wrong eather with my selected sopcinfo or with the BSP. Maybe you can give me some advice, tell me if you need more information ! :)
Thank you :D***

**Here are some screenshots of my development environment:**

https://de.scribd.com/document/452954331/Altera-Nios-II-BSP-Summary

https://de.scribd.com/document/452954367/Question-1